# Can a printer be held liable for e.g. copyright infringement?

Tags: united-states, copyright

An author knows when s/he has copied material and possibly infringed on someone's copyright, and a publisher is supposed to take "reasonable" steps to determine whether or not an author has done so.

But can a printer be held liable for such infringement? The printer's position is something like, "I was hired to print such-and-such and so I did. How would I know if it infringes on someone else's rights?"

Comment: Or how about a [cake decorator](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/trump-cake-louisiana_us_57d0ce2ae4b06a74c9f2a93f)? :)

Comment: Some printers and photocopiers already try to avoid money counterfeiting by identifying some pattern in some money bills. I'm not sure if this is law or manufacturers by their own.